# How to use a loss function that is not differentiable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to find a codebook at the output of a fully connected neural network which chooses points such that the minimum distance (Euclidean norm) between the so produced codebook is maximized. The input to the neural network is the points that need to be mapped into higher dimension of the output space.

For instance, if the input dimension is 2 and output dimension is 3, the following mapping (and any permutations) works best:
 00 - 000,
 01 - 011,
 10 - 101,
 11 - 110

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import itertools


input_bits = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='input_bits')
code_out = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 3], name='code_out')
np.random.seed(1331)


def find_code(message):
    weight1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01, size=[2, 3])
    init1 = tf.constant_initializer(weight1)
    out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=message, units=3, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, kernel_initializer=init1)
    return out


code = find_code(input_bits)

distances = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(i+1, 3):
        distances.append(tf.linalg.norm(code_out[i]-code_out[j]))
min_dist = tf.reduce_min(distances)
# avg_dist = tf.reduce_mean(distances)

loss = -min_dist

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

init_variables = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_variables)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

count = int(1e4)

for i in range(count):
    input_bit = [list(k) for k in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=2)]
    code_preview = sess.run(code, feed_dict={input_bits: input_bit})
    sess.run(opt, feed_dict={input_bits: input_bit, code_out: code_preview})
```

Since the loss function itself is not differentiable, I am getting the error

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
```

Am I doing something silly or is there a way to circumvent this? Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your loss function has to be differentiable with respect to some parameters. In your case, there are no parameters therefore you would be computing a derivative of a constant function which is 0. Moreover, in your code you have the following line:

```
code = find_code(input_bits)
```

which is not used any further. Based on the code, I assume that you want to change this line:

```
distances.append(tf.linalg.norm(code_out[i]-code_out[j]))
```

to:

```
distances.append(tf.linalg.norm(code[i]-code_out[j]))
```

Therefore, you would be using the `tf.layers.dense` that you have, thus include a parameter which can be used to compute the gradient of the loss with respect to that parameter.

---

Moreover, you don't need to worry whether a TF operation is differentiable or not. In fact, all TF ops are differentiable. When it comes to the `tf.reduce_min()`, please check [this link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/21871/how-does-tensorflow-compute-gradients-of-reduce-min-operation).

Comment: thank you for your reply. I still have the basic doubt, the loss function, computed using ```tf.reduce_min()``` is still not differentiable. Won't that be a concern?

Comment: One last question. When you said ```distances.append(tf.linalg.norm(code[i]-code_out[j]))```, did you mean ```distances.append(tf.linalg.norm(code[i]-code[j]))```? If not, is there any reason to use ```code_out``` placeholder?

Comment: Definitely no. If you do `code[i] - code[j]`, for all the weights of the dense layer will be pushed to zero because thats when the error will be lowest. If you want to train the neural network in a supervised fashion, you have to compute the mismatch between the neural network's output `code[i]` and the ground truth output `code_out[i]`that you will provide using the placeholder. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But ```code_out``` is not the ground truth. It is the output of the network for some bit combination. Its value is computed in the first and second line within the for loop. Also my loss function is ```-min_dist```, so pushing it to zero would not be favorable right? Ideally it should update weights such that the value of ```min_dist``` is maximized, so that the loss function is minimized. Isn't that right? Sorry for the long comment. Thanks

Comment: The neural network tries to minimize the error function. So instead of taking `-min_dist`, just take `min_dist`, and that should be sufficient. `code_out` is not the output of the neural network as per your code, since it is not obtained through the neural network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198170/discussion-between-gorjan-and-learner).